# Java 7 Objects class

Tags: java, java-7

There is a [`public final class Objects`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) in Java 7 that extendes the `java.lang.Object` base class.

Will this by default be the base class like or do we need to call the method on "Objects" class and call the corresponding methods?

Comment: Please, improve grammar. I can not understand what are you saying .... asking ...

Comment: After reading your question four times, I still do not understand it...

Comment: The way I understand is - is `Objects` replacing `Object` as a base class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Nothing changes. The [`Objects`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class is simply an utility class. It has only static methods, it's in the `util` package, and does what `ObjectUtils` from commons-lang is doing.

Comment: +1 (or Objects in Guava)

Comment: +1. Please note the 's' at the end of the name: `Objects`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but this sounds like a good bet for the correct answer ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Objects is final and it extends Object giving you null safe utilities.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `final` keyword.  No other class could `extend Objects`.